# Yii2 hide form field onchange radio

Tags: javascript, yii2, hide, onchange

I have a `radioList` with 2 values, 1 and 2.
I would like to hide `textInput` if the radio is set to 2.
I have tried:

```
$script = <<< JS

$(document).ready(function () {
    if(document.getElementById('radio').val() == '2' ) {
        document.getElementById('textInput').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('textInput').hide();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('textInput').show();
    }
});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);

echo $form->field($model, 'radio')->radioList(['1' => '1', '2' => '2'], ['id' => 'radio']);
echo $form->field($model, 'textInput')->textInput(['id' => 'textInput']);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show your html please

Comment: What html do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems with your code

- You are not loading/registring the script anywhere using `$this->registerJs($script,\yii\web\View::POS_READY)`.
- There isn't any method with the name `.val()` but `.value` when using javascript `document.getElementById()`.
- There isn't any method `.show()` and `.hide()` in javascript
- Then even if you would have done the above steps it would still not work because you are not **binding** any event to the radio inputs your script is just an inline script which would be called when the page is loaded.
- The id `radio` you are providing in the `radioList` will be `id` of the container in which all the radio list inputs are residing.
- And you need to hide the complete container of the input, not just the input so that the label is also hidden and shown along with the input.

Since you have used the javascript tag I am using `addEventListner` to bind the event see the code below and add it to the top of your view.

```
$script = <<< JS
document.querySelectorAll("#radio input[type='radio']").forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(this.value == '2' ) {
            document.querySelector('#textInput').parentElement.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.querySelector('#textInput').parentElement.style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to add `registerJs` in here somehow but it was there.

Comment: @user2511599 its ok you can note the rest of the points and add the script on top your page and it will work correctly